# How can I pass a type hint that MyPy will accept as a parameter to a function which defines a function internally?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to write unit tests for types we're using with [beartype](https://github.com/beartype/beartype), our runtime type checker. The tests run as expected, however MyPy will not accept the code.

The following code works, however the MyPy check fails.

```py
def typecheck(val: Any, t: type):
    """
    isinstance() does not allow things like Tuple[Int]
    """

    @beartype
    def f(v: t):
        return v

    try:
        f(val)
    except BeartypeCallHintPepParamException:
        return False
    return True

# passes
def test_typecheck():
    assert typecheck((1,), Tuple[int])
    assert not typecheck((1,), Tuple[str])
```

However, I get the following error. The linked to page isn't helpful.

```
error: Variable "t" is not valid as a type
note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
```

How do I properly annotate this? Ive tried `TypeVar`s but I get the same error.

Comment: Function annotations aren't values; you can't do this, at least not without using `exec` (which `mypy` probably can't deal with anyway).

Comment: `mypy` does *static* type checking; `f` does not exist until you actually execute the code.

Comment: Maybe `T = TypeVar('T'); def typecheck(..., t: Type[T]): ... def f(v: T)`?

Comment: @chepner This passes MyPy but causes the unit tests to fail. Presumably since the passed param `t` no longer being used as the type.

Comment: You can't use `t` as a type hint at all. The purpose of the type var `T` is to parameterize the type hint for `t`. `Type[T]` indicates that `t` is some type, rather than value of type `T`, so that later `def f(v: T)` indicates that `v` has whatever type was passed as `t`.

Comment: But I do see what the issue is.

Comment: What about assigning the type hint explicitly, rather than using function annotations? `f.__annotations__['x'] = t`? (Wrote this up as an answer; I'll delete if it turns out not to work.)

Answer (score 1):

Assign the type hint directly, rather than letting it be assigned via a function annotation.

```
def typecheck(val, t):
    """
    isinstance() does not allow things like Tuple[Int]
    """

    @beartype
    def f(v):
        return v
    f.__annotations__['v'] = t

    try:
        f(val)
    except BeartypeCallHintPepParamException:
        return False
    return True

# passes
def test_typecheck():
    assert typecheck((1,), Tuple[int])
    assert not typecheck((1,), Tuple[str])
```